# Android temp update spinner before it gets values from SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I'm wondering if there is some trick to get the spinner updated from an edittext and onClick, before it gets committed to the database and retrieve from there? The list and the spinnerAdapter are set for retrieving values from database, so I'm aware that this question might be stupid.

I was thinking of this logic: enter some text to edittext, click ok, then temporary update the spinner with this text, before it goes to database, then do some other stuff in the activity and last commit everything to database. When you then close and open your activity again, the temporary value is lost, but the spinner gets populatet with the same value, but this time from database.

here is some code:

```
    public class Vnos extends Activity {

 //... some values

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//... 

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        final List<VnosiDB> spinerItems = datasource.getAllNiz();
        final ArrayAdapter<VnosiDB> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<VnosiDB>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinerItems);
        spinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        String nizIzSpinerja = spinner.getItemAtPosition(
                spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
        nizDB = nizIzSpinerja;

        // nov niz

        novNiz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dodaj);
        novNiz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Vnos.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.nov_niz);

                TextView okNov = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okNovNiz);
                okNov.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        EditText inputNiz = (EditText) dialog
                                .findViewById(R.id.niz);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        nizDB = inputNiz.getText().toString();
                        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }

        });


// ...some other code...
//...
//.. then, here I commit everything to database...

        shrani = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shrani);
        shrani.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                vnosDB = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

                datasource.createVnos(zacetekDB, razlikaDB, nizDB, deloDB,
                        postavkaDB, dodatekDB, opisDB, vnosDB);
                datasource.close();
                Toast test = Toast.makeText(Vnos.this, "Vnos " + deloDB
                        + " uspešen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                test.show();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.sandpit.jazstudent.URE"));
                finish();

            }
        });


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `ArrayAdapter`, which is loaded by `List<VnosiDB>`. I assume that `VnosiDB` represents a record from the database. Why don't you just put a temporary record in this list when you need it?

```
List<VnosiDB> spinerItems = new ArrayList<VnosiDB>();
VnosiDB tempRec = new VnosiDB();
//set some values to the properties if you need to
spinnerItems.add(tempRec);
//populate the spinner with the temp record
```

Comment: Yes, VnosiDB represents a record from database. The first error I get when I trew that code into my first onClick is: Cannot instantiate the type List<VnosiDB> - and if I erase the line List<VnosiDB> spinerItems = new List<VnosiDB>(); and do:tempRec = (VnosiDB) inputNiz.getText();, I get the cannot cast error in the log.

Comment: my bad, List is interface, use `List<VnosiDB> spinerItems = new ArrayList<VnosiDB>();`

Comment: Still getting the cannot cast to VnosiDB. VnosiDB is a class where the essential database methods are in, like: getId, setId, get.., set..,...

Comment: what's the point of this `tempRec = (VnosiDB) inputNiz.getText()`. It is normal you cannot cast String to VnosiDB. What do you even expect to be the result of this??

Comment: I have to update the spinner from the edittext... If I dont try to assign tempRec some value - in this example from an edittext - then the spinner gets updated with a blank field.

Comment: then set the value from the edit text to the field of tempRec for example, if you show a field called `name` from the record, make `tempRec.setName(inputNiz.getText());`

Comment: It works, but in the onClick method, you have to erase the List<VnosiDB> spinerItems = new ArrayList<VnosiDB> of your solution. Then it works fine.